# convert nested json to pandas dataframe of specific format

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I pulled this nested json data from database and I think it's a list of dictionary. (I am not sure, I am new to python)

I tried many codes posted on stack overflow but none of them addressed my particular problem, I always ran into errors...

The data is quite large, there are in total more than 100 usageId. I'm only showing the first one, which looks like this:

```
[{'usageId': 'e83f43f8-ec4a-402d-a64e-d74b6f1df4a7',
  'assessment_status_date': '2022-03-28',
  'assessment_date': '2020-12-07',
  'usage_assessment': 'Level 1',
  'has_l3test': None,
  'compensating_control': None,
  'recommendations': None,
  'test_category': {'Usage Reconciliation': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Health and Welfare Plan + Usage Reconciliation': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'Test out of scope',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2019-10-02',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'In Progress',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Data Agreements': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Health and Welfare Plan + Data Agreements': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2019-10-02',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'In Progress',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Data Elements': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Health and Welfare Plan + Data Elements': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'The rationale provided for why the Usage contains no HPDEs appears valid',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2019-10-02',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'In Progress',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Computations': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Health and Welfare Plan + Computations': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Lineage': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Health and Welfare Plan + Lineage': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Metadata': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Health and Welfare Plan + Metadata': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'Valid',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-07-02',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Data Quality Monitoring': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Health and Welfare Plan + Data Quality Monitoring': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2019-08-09',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'HPU Source Reliability': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Health and Welfare Plan + HPU Source Reliability': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2019-10-02',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'In Progress',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Change Notification': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Health and Welfare Plan + Change Notification': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None}},
  'assessment_status': 'In Progress',
  'recommendation_indicator': None,
  'assessment_justification': None,
  'revalidation_justification': None},
 {'usageId': 'b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6dd1e1edce64',
  'assessment_status_date': '2022-03-28',
  'assessment_date': '2020-12-07',
  'usage_assessment': 'Level 1',
  'has_l3test': None,
  'compensating_control': None,
  'recommendations': None,
  'test_category': {'Usage Reconciliation': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'New or Changed Usage Reconciles with Prior Usage': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-10-23',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Data Agreements': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Data Agreement Reviewed and Approved in Last Year': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-07-21',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Data Elements': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'HPDEs Identified': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'Valid',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-07-02',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'},
     'HPDE Justification is Documented and Reasonable': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-02-28',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'},
     'HPDE Identification Rationale is Valid': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-02-28',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'},
     'Usage Output is Documented and Metadata is Registered': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-08-07',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'},
     'Data Element Metadata is in Curated State': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': 'tat00000',
      'test_execution_status': 'In Progress',
      'test_result': None},
     'Secured Data Indicator Consistency': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None},
     'HPDE Metadata is in Curated State': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'Valid',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-07-02',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Computations': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Usage Outcome is Accurate': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Lineage': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Lineage is Accurate Reflection of Run': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None},
     'Partial Lineage from Authoritiative or Acceptable Source to Originating Source Exists and is Reasonable': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None},
     'Lineage from Usage to Authoritative or Acceptable Source is Complete': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None},
     'Quality is Sufficient': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Metadata': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Usage Description is Valid': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-02-28',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'},
     "Usage SME's EID Status is Valid": {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'Valid',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-07-02',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'},
     'Usage AE': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'Valid',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-07-02',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Data Quality Monitoring': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Data Defect Tracking Process is Reasonable': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-02-28',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'},
     'Data Movement is Reasonable': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-10-23',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Fail'},
     'DQ Rules and Thresholds are Comprehensive': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'In Progress',
      'test_result': 'Fail'},
     'Data Defect Tracking Process is Operating Effectively': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None},
     'DQ Monitoring Plan is Reasonable': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-10-22',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'HPU Source Reliability': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Usage Consumes from Acceptable Source': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-10-23',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Fail'},
     'Usage Consumes from Approved Source': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Change Notification': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Change Notification Process is Reasonable': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-07-21',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'},
     'Change Notification Process is Operating Effectively': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None}},
  'assessment_status': 'In Progress',
  'recommendation_indicator': None,
  'assessment_justification': None,
  'revalidation_justification': None},
 {'usageId': 'c67a1567-2de3-4826-97bb-99838b405acd',
  'assessment_status_date': '2022-03-28',
  'assessment_date': '2020-12-07',
  'usage_assessment': 'Level 1',
  'has_l3test': None,
  'compensating_control': None,
  'recommendations': None,
  'test_category': {'Usage Reconciliation': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Provided Health Insur Offer & Coverage Information Returns (1094C) + Usage Reconciliation': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'Test out of scope',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2019-10-02',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'In Progress',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Data Agreements': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Provided Health Insur Offer & Coverage Information Returns (1094C) + Data Agreements': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2019-10-21',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Data Elements': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Provided Health Insur Offer & Coverage Information Returns (1094C) + Data Elements': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'Valid',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-07-02',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Computations': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Provided Health Insur Offer & Coverage Information Returns (1094C) + Computations': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Lineage': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Provided Health Insur Offer & Coverage Information Returns (1094C) + Lineage': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Metadata': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Provided Health Insur Offer & Coverage Information Returns (1094C) + Metadata': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'Valid',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2020-07-02',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Data Quality Monitoring': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Provided Health Insur Offer & Coverage Information Returns (1094C) + Data Quality Monitoring': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
      'latest_test_result_date': '2019-10-21',
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
      'test_result': 'Pass without Compensating Controls'}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'HPU Source Reliability': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Provided Health Insur Offer & Coverage Information Returns (1094C) + HPU Source Reliability': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None},
   'Change Notification': {'test_category_assessment_date': None,
    'last_updated_by': None,
    'test_execution': {'Provided Health Insur Offer & Coverage Information Returns (1094C) + Change Notification': {'evidence_capture': None,
      'test_result_justification': None,
      'latest_test_result_date': None,
      'last_updated_by': None,
      'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
      'test_result': None}},
    'test_category_assessment': None,
    'test_category_status': None,
    'test_category_assessment_justification': None}},
  'assessment_status': 'In Progress',
  'recommendation_indicator': None,
  'assessment_justification': None,
  'revalidation_justification': None}]
```

I want to convert it into 2 tables. I've created 2 tables in excel, it'll be something like that.

[image: first table]

[image: second table]

I apologize if I asked a stupid question or the way I formatted my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Using the updated data with multiple `usageId` (there are 3 of them)，I did the following processing steps and output `df4` with the relevant columns of interest, please have a look:

```
import pandas as pd

d = [{'usageId': 'e83f43f8-ec4a-402d-a64e-d74b6f1df4a7',
  'assessment_status_date': '2022-03-28',
  'assessment_date': '2020-12-07',
  'usage_assessment': <truncated>  ]

df4 = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)    #df1 = from dictionary d
for usageId in set(df1['usageId']):
    df2 = df1[df1['usageId'] == usageId]    #df2 = filtered based on each usageId, total more than 100 usageId
    test_category = list({k.split('+')[0].strip(): v for d in lis for k, v in d.items()}.keys())[0]
    lis = pd.DataFrame(df2['test_category'].values.tolist()[0]).T['test_execution'].values.tolist()
    df3 = pd.DataFrame({k.split('+')[-1].strip(): v for d in lis for k, v in d.items()}).T    #df3 = extracted column 'test_execution'
    df3['test_category'] = test_category
    df3['usageId'] = usageId
    df4 = pd.concat([df4, df3], axis=0)    #df4 = compiled test_execution for all usageId
    df1['test_category'][df1['usageId']==usageId] = test_category
print(df4)
```

Output:

```
                               evidence_capture      test_result_justification latest_test_result_date last_updated_by test_execution_status                    test_result                  test_category                        usageId
Usage Reconciliation                       None              Test out of scope              2019-10-02            None           In Progress                           None        Health and Welfare Plan  e83f43f8-ec4a-402d-a64e-d7...
Data Agreements                            None                            xxx              2019-10-02            None           In Progress                           None        Health and Welfare Plan  e83f43f8-ec4a-402d-a64e-d7...
Data Elements                              None  The rationale provided for...              2019-10-02            None           In Progress                           None        Health and Welfare Plan  e83f43f8-ec4a-402d-a64e-d7...
Computations                               None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None        Health and Welfare Plan  e83f43f8-ec4a-402d-a64e-d7...
Lineage                                    None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None        Health and Welfare Plan  e83f43f8-ec4a-402d-a64e-d7...
Metadata                                   None                          Valid              2020-07-02            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...        Health and Welfare Plan  e83f43f8-ec4a-402d-a64e-d7...
Data Quality Monitoring                    None                            xxx              2019-08-09            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...        Health and Welfare Plan  e83f43f8-ec4a-402d-a64e-d7...
HPU Source Reliability                     None                            xxx              2019-10-02            None           In Progress                           None        Health and Welfare Plan  e83f43f8-ec4a-402d-a64e-d7...
Change Notification                        None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None        Health and Welfare Plan  e83f43f8-ec4a-402d-a64e-d7...
New or Changed Usage Reconc...             None                            xxx              2020-10-23            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Data Agreement Reviewed and...             None                            xxx              2020-07-21            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
HPDEs Identified                           None                          Valid              2020-07-02            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
HPDE Justification is Docum...             None                            xxx              2020-02-28            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
HPDE Identification Rationa...             None                            xxx              2020-02-28            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Usage Output is Documented ...             None                            xxx              2020-08-07            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Data Element Metadata is in...             None                            xxx                    None        tat00000           In Progress                           None  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Secured Data Indicator Cons...             None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
HPDE Metadata is in Curated...             None                          Valid              2020-07-02            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Usage Outcome is Accurate                  None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Lineage is Accurate Reflect...             None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Partial Lineage from Author...             None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Lineage from Usage to Autho...             None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Quality is Sufficient                      None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Usage Description is Valid                 None                             xx              2020-02-28            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Usage SME's EID Status is V...             None                          Valid              2020-07-02            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Usage AE                                   None                          Valid              2020-07-02            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Data Defect Tracking Proces...             None                            xxx              2020-02-28            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Data Movement is Reasonable                None                            xxx              2020-10-23            None             Completed                           Fail  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
DQ Rules and Thresholds are...             None                           None                    None            None           In Progress                           Fail  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Data Defect Tracking Proces...             None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
DQ Monitoring Plan is Reaso...             None                            xxx              2020-10-22            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Usage Consumes from Accepta...             None                            xxx              2020-10-23            None             Completed                           Fail  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Usage Consumes from Approve...             None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Change Notification Process...             None                            xxx              2020-07-21            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Change Notification Process...             None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  New or Changed Usage Recon...  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...
Usage Reconciliation                       None              Test out of scope              2019-10-02            None           In Progress                           None  Provided Health Insur Offe...  c67a1567-2de3-4826-97bb-99...
Data Agreements                            None                            xxx              2019-10-21            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  Provided Health Insur Offe...  c67a1567-2de3-4826-97bb-99...
Data Elements                              None                          Valid              2020-07-02            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  Provided Health Insur Offe...  c67a1567-2de3-4826-97bb-99...
Computations                               None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  Provided Health Insur Offe...  c67a1567-2de3-4826-97bb-99...
Lineage                                    None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  Provided Health Insur Offe...  c67a1567-2de3-4826-97bb-99...
Metadata                                   None                          Valid              2020-07-02            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  Provided Health Insur Offe...  c67a1567-2de3-4826-97bb-99...
Data Quality Monitoring                    None                            xxx              2019-10-21            None             Completed  Pass without Compensating ...  Provided Health Insur Offe...  c67a1567-2de3-4826-97bb-99...
HPU Source Reliability                     None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  Provided Health Insur Offe...  c67a1567-2de3-4826-97bb-99...
Change Notification                        None                           None                    None            None           Not Started                           None  Provided Health Insur Offe...  c67a1567-2de3-4826-97bb-99...
```

The original `df1` is also updated; this table is linked to `df4` by `usageId` and `test_category`

```
                         usageId assessment_status_date assessment_date usage_assessment has_l3test compensating_control recommendations                  test_category assessment_status recommendation_indicator assessment_justification revalidation_justification
0  e83f43f8-ec4a-402d-a64e-d7...             2022-03-28      2020-12-07          Level 1       None                 None            None        Health and Welfare Plan       In Progress                     None                     None                       None
1  b3c9cbbd-fb72-46df-a4a3-6d...             2022-03-28      2020-12-07          Level 1       None                 None            None  New or Changed Usage Recon...       In Progress                     None                     None                       None
2  c67a1567-2de3-4826-97bb-99...             2022-03-28      2020-12-07          Level 1       None                 None            None  Provided Health Insur Offe...       In Progress                     None                     None                       None
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I got an error message KeyError: 0 when running your code. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: may I know which line is the error? (there are 2 lines with key 0)

Comment: do all the 'test_execution' look like this with ' + ' in between? `'test_execution': {'Health and Welfare Plan + Change Notification': ...<trancated>`

Comment: df2['test_category'][0] this line is highlighted. Yes,  all the 'test_execution' look like this.

Comment: there is always a '+' in between, and follow by the name of the category name (e.g. Change Notification), but the first part varies. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think I found the bug.. the code is working for me because I only have 1 usageId. Are you able to include another usageId in the `data` ?

Comment: yea, I updated the data to include few more records.

Comment: ok, the code should work now!

Comment: I suppose 'd' would be the whole file name?  I'm getting 'TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable' in here df2['test_category'].values.tolist()[0]['Usage Reconciliation']

Comment: i see, the data `d` has many variations in each record(usageId).. I've tried to generalise the code, pls have a look to see if it works

Comment: new error, says ```ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!```, in this line: ```pd.DataFrame(df2['test_category'].values.tolist()[0])```

Comment: are you able to share the whole `d` data to me from dropbox or google drive? It seems the data has too many variations in each record(usageId), so unable to generalise the code

Comment: i just solved it with by creating empty list and append them together! Thank you for the help though!

Comment: thanks, you should have sufficient reputations to upvote now!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it finally with the below code

```
for usage_json in assessment_json:
    if 'test_category' in usage_json:
        for tc in usage_json['test_category'].keys():
            if 'test_execution' in usage_json['test_category'][tc]:
                sub_te_df = pd.DataFrame(usage_json['test_category'][tc]['test_execution']).T
                sub_te_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
                sub_te_df = sub_te_df.rename(columns = {'index':'test_execution'})
                sub_te_df['usageId'] = usage_json['usageId']
                sub_te_df['test_category'] = tc
                usage_te_df_list.append(sub_te_df)

df_execution = pd.concat(usage_te_df_list).reset_index(drop=True)
```